# KineticJS Jerky Rotation on TransitionTo

Tags: ios, html, kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS in order to spin a wheel so it lands on a particular point.
What seems to happen is on iOS, the transition is jerky every 1 second. Is there a way to improve the performance of the render?

```
var dir = 1;
if(direction == "left"){
     dir = -1;
}
var PI = Math.PI;
wheel.transitionTo({    
    rotation: ((degrees*PI/6) + (dir *10*PI)),
    duration:7,
    easing:"ease-out"
})
```

Here's the link to the current project: http://dev.hitpointstudios.com/sessionm_wheelspin/trunk/

Notes:
- This only has happened. I have tested on a Droid 2, HTC Inspire and Galaxy S2 and the performance is good.

Answer (score 1):

looking into this. It's a side effect of the requestAnimationFrame method, in which the browser controls the dynamic frame rates.  I'm currently looking into implementing a custom requestAnimationFrame method that might be better controlled.